# Sigma additivity of Hausdorff measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As is known to us all, the Hausdorff measure satisfies the inequality below:
$$\mathcal H ^{s}\left(\bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1}F_i\right)\leq\sum^{\infty}_{i=1}\mathcal H^s(F_i).
$$
And there is equality in this inequality if the $\{F_i\}$ are disjoint Borel sets. I understand this equality when each $F_i$ has a positive distance between the other.

I wonder why the equality holds if the $\{F_i\}$ are disjoint Borel sets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ignore the bot. Hausdorff outer measure restricts to a measure on the Caratheodory measurable sets and sigma additivity applies for these

Comment: @FShrike I still think the Caratheodory criterion can only solve positive distance situations. Maybe there are some details I don't understand.

Comment: the caratheodory thing just follows from generalities. It must be sigma additive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction of Caratheodory (reference in Hausdorff's paper, among many more recent places) proves countable additivity on a family of "measurable" sets.  And that the the Borel sets are measurable.

*PLUG.*  See Chapter 5 in

*Edgar, Gerald A.*, [**Measure, topology, and fractal geometry**](https://mathoverflow.net/q/429868), Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics. New York etc.: Springer-Verlag. ix, 230 p. DM 58.00/hbk (1990). [ZBL0727.28003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0727.28003).

in particular Section 5.2, "Method I".

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I have forgotten these details of constructing measures. I need to review it.